# svn command to create repository

Tags: svn, cmd, tortoisesvn

When I execute the following command in command prompt, we are getting error. We would like to create svn repository using command prompt

svnadmin create Shipment

Error: svnadmin is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Did you actually install Subversion? What's in your PATH?

Comment: I have installed Tortoise SVN . It is in C Drive , Programme files

Comment: Do a search of this site for the error message **not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file** There are many existing questions that will explain the problem and how to solve it.. A simple search of the site for the error message should be the very first thing you do, long before you post a new question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769/what-is-the-reason-for-x-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0):

You can install [VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/) and [create a repository via the management console](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/#Adding-Repositories) or [using PowerShell](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#New-SvnRepository).

The original problem with the error "Error: svnadmin is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." is generally unrelated to Subversion. Make sure that you have SVN command line tools installed and that they are in your %PATH% environment variable.

PS TortoiseSVN is a **SVN client**, not a server.